# Debugging pyspark: IndexError("list index out of range") / JavaArray

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to debug some `pyspark` code, but the debugger fails with `IndexError` whenever it hits the line that creates a `SparkSession`:

```
SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()
```

The exception is raised by the `JavaArray` class, `__compute_index` method (defined in `java_collections.py`):

```
raise IndexError("list index out of range")
```

However, running tests manually (without a debugger) works as expected (i.e. tests run successfully). Also, surprisingly, the problem can be mitigated by putting a breakpoint in a line which calls `getOrCreate` and executing that line in a *Debug Console* manually. After doing that, resuming debugger works as expected, i.e. `IndexError` does not appear anymore.

What's causing the `IndexError`? How I can resolve it without invoking `getOrCreate` manually in the Debug Console each time?

*pyspark version: 2.4.4, Python 3.7.4, OS: Linux*

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve the issue by toggling off the following breakpoints: *Raised Exceptions, Uncaught Exceptions, User Uncaught Exceptions*. The `IndexError` was most likely caused by the lack of connection available in the `GatewayClient.deque` when calling

```
SparkSession.builder.(...).getOrCreate()
```

I suspect that it must have been caused by the asynchronicity of the debugging thread/process that tried to access the connection before it became available.